# How can I fix this error "the value of 'x1' is not usable in a constant expression" ? static_assert

Tags: c++, c++11

Given the following code ( *only for the example*) :

```
    int x1 = 4;
    int x2 = 5;
    static_assert(x1 != x2 ,"Error");
```

I get the following error:

> the value of 'x1' is not usable in a constant expression

How can I fix it ?

---

Note: I looking for a way to fix it without change the definitions of the variables in this way:

```
const int x1 = 4;
const int x2 = 5;
```

But, I want to fix it only by change the the line of `static_assert(..)`

Comment: I will never understand these "I know what the correct solution is but I'm looking for something else" questions.

Comment: @interjay Because that maybe exists other solution that can solve it in other way..

Comment: If the values are not constants, you would have to resort to an old runtime `assert()`.

Comment: @Software_t But we don't know what your limitations are that prevent the correct solution from solving your problem. For example, is a run-time assert good enough?

Comment: @interjay Yes is good too. (So you can try to advise solution in according to the question). [like Galik]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a *runtime* assertion like:

```
#include <cassert>

// ...

int x1 = 4;
int x2 = 5;

assert(x1 != x2);
```

**Note:** Runtime *assertions* using [assert](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert) only apply when compiling in debug mode, they are removed when compiling in *release* mode. Because of this they do not slow the application down. They are **zero cost** so you could (and arguably *should*) use them liberally to check boundary conditions and general correctness.

An important consideration (props @Bathsheba) is that these *assertions* should **not** invoke ***side effects*** because then the behavior between the *debug version* and the *release version* would be different.

eg.

```
// in the release version x2 will NOT be incremented!!!
assert(x1 != x2++); // BAD!!
```

Answer (score 8):

Well, the proper fix is

```
constexpr int x1 = 4;
constexpr int x2 = 5;
```

Otherwise, how does the compiler know (in full generality and consistency) that `x1` and `x2` are compile-time evaluable constant expressions?

If `x1` and `x2` need to be `int` types, then you need to use a *run-time* assertion, such as `assert`:

```
assert(x1 != x2)
```

But do note that the expression passed to `assert` is **not** evaluated if `NDEBUG` is defined. That can cause issues with different build configurations if the expression has side-effects.

Reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert